# Batch script for move files into corresponding folders with similar name

Tags: windows, batch

I have created folders ranging from SRR11219690 - SRR11221063 (1537 folders in total)

I have then downloaded the following SRR files:
SRR11219690.sra
SRR11219690.sra.vdbcache

until

SRR11221063.sra
SRR11221063.sra.vdbcache

I need to batch move the .sra and .vdbcache into its corresponding name folder. Can someone please assist with creating a batch script to move the 2 files into its corresponding name folder?

I am assuming there needs to be a loop involved with the changing of the last 4 SRR digits?

Comment: Can we see what you have tried so far

Comment: that is the issue, i dont have coding experience, so i don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually the last 5 digits that need to be adjusted for your purposes. If the beginning of each folder/file is `SRR112` and the last five digits range from `19690` and `21063`. i.e. SRR11219690 to SRR11221063.

Here is an example windows batch script that will perform the task of copying files to their matching folder name. Save this script as `copySRR.bat` and run it. I would adjust this script to only range through a few folder numbers to ensure it is working as expected before running it for every file. For example, to adjust the range, change the values in the `for` loop from `(19690, 1, 21063)` to `(19690, 1, 19691)`.

The lines with `REM` are comments, and are there to clarify what each section is doing.

You will need to modify `source_dir` to the path containing the SRR files and folders. This script assumes the SRR files are in the same path as the SRR folders.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Set the source directory where the .sra and .vdbcache files are located
set "source_dir=C:\Path\To\Your\Source\Directory"

REM Set the base name for the folders (e.g., SRR112)
set "base_name=SRR112"

REM Loop through the range of folder numbers
for /l %%i in (19690, 1, 21063) do (
    REM Generate the full SRR number by appending the current number to the base_name
    set "srr_number=!base_name!%%i"

    REM Check if the folder exists before moving the files
    if exist "%source_dir%\!srr_number!\" (
        REM Move .sra and .vdbcache files to the corresponding folder
        move "%source_dir%\!srr_number!.sra" "%source_dir%\!srr_number!\"
        move "%source_dir%\!srr_number!.sra.vdbcache" "%source_dir%\!srr_number!\"
    ) else (
        echo Folder !srr_number! not found.
    )
)

echo All files moved into their corresponding folders.
```

Comment: You are a legend Jim! It works perfectly. I adjusted the script to run for 4 folders/files and it works perfectly. Once I get all the files, I will run script on all, cheers!